# onclicklistener for notification

Tags: android, notifications

I had set a notification in my app. Its working fine. If i click the notification in `statusbar` it takes to my app.
    Now i need to set some work if the notification is clicked where can i set this? 
    Is there any method that implicitly got invoked when a notification is clicked?
    Also i want to remove that notification if it is clicked,how to do so?

this is my code

```
notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
Intent inty=getIntent();
note = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "New E-mail", System.currentTimeMillis());  
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, inty, 0);  
note.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, "New E-mail", "You have one unread message.", intent);
notifManager.notify(R.string.search_hint, note);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add some extra data to the intent and then in your activity look for it in the onCreate and onNewIntent methods.

For example:

```
inty.putExtra("came from notification", true);
```

You can then read that out via the intent passed to onNewIntent or in onCreate by using getIntent().

```
intent.getBooleanExtra("came from notification", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call broadcastReceiver it may helpful for your requirement,

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, dummy_activity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                notificationIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | 
                                Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

// Now, once this dummy activity starts send a broad cast to your parent activity and finish the pending activity
//remember you need to register your broadcast action here to receive.
BroadcastReceiver call_method = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action_name = intent.getAction();
        if (action_name.equals("call_method")) {
            // call your method here and do what ever you want.
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(call_method, new IntentFilter("call_method"));
```